# how to add a property to existing node neo4j cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

i have created a new node  labeled User

```
CREATE (n:User)
```

i want to add a name property to my User node i tried it by

```
MATCH (n { label: 'User' })
SET n.surname = 'Taylor'
RETURN n
```

but seems it is not affecting .

how can i add properties to a already created node .

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Rolf Hey very sorry ,  I just now saw your comment :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your matching by label is incorrect, the query should be:

```
MATCH (n:User)
SET n.surname = 'Taylor'
RETURN n
```

What you wrote is: "match a user whose label *property* is User".
Label isn't a property, this is a notion apart.

As Michael mentioned, if you want to match a node with a specific property, you've got two alternatives:

```
MATCH (n:User {surname: 'Some Surname'})
```

or:

```
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE n.surname = 'Some Surname'
```

Now the combo:

```
MATCH (n:User {surname: 'Some Surname'})
SET n.surname = 'Taylor'
RETURN n
```

Comment: that's Great . it is working , also i want to add surname property to a single Node named user using the ID , please give me a help also for that . Thank you very much

Comment: MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.firstname = 'Andres'
SET n.surname = 'Taylor'
RETURN n

Comment: or MATCH (n:User {firstname:'Andres'})
SET n.surname = 'Taylor'
RETURN n

Comment: I want to add new property in existing node using csv file , how to do that ? I use this one but it is not working - USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://192.168.11.121/movie-reco-db/person_node.csv" AS row
MATCH (n:Person)
SET n.appId = row.app_id
RETURN n